# Problems using my find method in my program

Tags: java, list, find

I'm trying to use a find function to find called index to find every entry saved with the first name entered. My program prints out the contacts I'm trying to find, but then also prints out the entire list of contacts entered. I can't find out why. I keep trying different things, but it either only prints the first entry or the whole list. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
class Entry {
public String fname, lname, number, note;
}
class PBN {
public static Entry[] contactList;
public static int num_entries;
public static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    int i;
    char C;
    String code, Command;
    contactList = new Entry[999];
    num_entries = 0;
    try {
        readPhoneBook("PhoneBook.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    System.out.println("Codes are entered as 1 to 8 characters.\nUse" +
            " \"e\" for enter," +
            " \"f\" for find," +
            " \"l\" for listing all the entries," +
            " \"m\" for removing the entries by name," +
            " \"d\" for removing the entries by phone number," +
            " \"a\" for sort alphabetically by first name," +
            " \"n\" for sort alphabetically by last name," +
            " \"p\" for sort by number," +
            " \"q\" to quit.");
    Command = null;
    C = ' ';
    while(true) { // loop infinitely

        System.out.print("Command: ");
        Command = stdin.nextLine();
        C = Command.charAt(0);
        switch (C) {
            case 'e': addContact(); break;
            case 'f':
                code = stdin.next();
                stdin.nextLine();
                i = index(code);
            case 'l':
                listAllContacts(); break;
            case 'q': // when user wants to quit
                CopyPhoneBookToFile("PhoneBook.txt");
                System.out.println("Quitting the application. All the entries are "
                        + "stored in the file PhoneBook1.txt");
                System.exit(0); // simply terminate the execution
            case 'a':
                sortList1();
                break;
            case 'n':
                sortList2();
                break;
            case 'p':
                sortListByPhoneNumber();
                break;
            case 'm': // m for deleting a contact; delete by first name
                System.out.print("Enter the first name of a contact you wish to remove : ");
                String fname = stdin.nextLine(); // read the contact number
                removeEntry(fname); // remove the number from the entries
                break;
            case 'o': // m for deleting a contact; delete by last name
                System.out.print("Enter the last name of a contact you wish to remove : ");
                String lname = stdin.nextLine(); // read the contact number
                removeEntry2(lname); // remove the number from the entries
                break;
            case 'd': // m for deleting a contact; delete by phone number
                System.out.print("Enter the number of a contact you wish to remove : ");
                String number = stdin.nextLine(); // read the contact number
                removeEntry1(number); // remove the number from the entries
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid command Please enter the command again!!!");
        }
    }
}
public static void readPhoneBook(String FileName) throws Exception {
    File F;
    F = new File(FileName);
    Scanner S = new Scanner(F);
    while (S.hasNextLine()) {
        contactList[num_entries]= new Entry();
        contactList[num_entries].fname = S.next();
        contactList[num_entries].lname = S.next();
        contactList[num_entries].number = S.next();
        contactList[num_entries].note = S.nextLine();
        num_entries++;
    }
    S.close();
}
public static void addContact() {
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    String fname = stdin.nextLine();
    String lname;
    String number;
    String pattern = "^\\(?(\\d{3})?\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ](\\d{4})$";
    while (fname.length() > 8 || fname.length() < 1) {
        System.out.println("First name must be between 1 to 8 characters.");
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        fname = stdin.nextLine();
    }
    contactList[num_entries] = new Entry();
    contactList[num_entries].fname = fname;
    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    lname = stdin.nextLine();
    while (lname.length() > 8 || lname.length() < 1) {
        System.out.println("First name must be between 1 to 8 characters.");
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        lname = stdin.nextLine();
    }
    contactList[num_entries].lname = lname;
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    number = stdin.nextLine(); // read the number

    while(!number.matches(pattern)) { // as long as user doesnt enters correct format, loop
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.out.println("Not proper digit format! Use \"012-3456\", \"(012)345-6789\"" +
                ", or \"012-345-6789\" format.");
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        number = stdin.nextLine();
    }
    contactList[num_entries].number = number;

    System.out.print("Enter Notes: ");
    contactList[num_entries].note = stdin.nextLine();

    num_entries++;
    System.out.println();
}
public static int index(String Key) {
    // Function to get the index of a key from an array
    // if not found, returns -1
    Key=Key.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(Key);
    for (int i=0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        if (contactList[i].fname.equals(Key)) {
            if (i >= 0) displayContact(contactList[i]);
            //System.out.println();
            //return i;
        }    // Found the Key, return index.
    }
    return -1;
}
public static void displayContact(Entry contact) {
    System.out.println("--"+ contact.fname+"\t");
    System.out.println("--"+ contact.lname+"\t");
    System.out.println("--"+ contact.number+"\t");
    System.out.println("--"+ contact.note);
    System.out.println("");
}
public static void listAllContacts() {
    for(Entry e : contactList) {
        if(e != null)
            displayContact(e);
        else
            break;
    }
}
public static void sortList1() {
    int i;
    Entry temp;
    temp = new Entry();
    for (int j = 0; j< num_entries; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < num_entries; i++) {
            if (contactList[j].fname.compareToIgnoreCase(contactList[i].fname)> 0) {
                temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = contactList[i];
                contactList[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }listAllContacts();
}
public static void sortList2() {
    int i;
    Entry temp;
    temp = new Entry();
    for (int j = 0; j< num_entries; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < num_entries; i++) {
            if (contactList[j].lname.compareToIgnoreCase(contactList[i].lname)> 0) {
                temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = contactList[i];
                contactList[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }listAllContacts();
}
public static void CopyPhoneBookToFile(String FileName) throws Exception{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
    PrintStream P = new PrintStream( out );
    for (int i=0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        P.println(
                contactList[i].fname + "\t" +
                        contactList[i].lname + "\t" +
                        contactList[i].number + "\t" +
                        contactList[i].note);
    }
}
private static void removeEntry(String fname) {
    Entry[] newcontactList = new Entry[contactList.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(Entry e : contactList) {
        if(e == null) break; // if an entry is null then break the loop
        if(e.fname.equals(fname)) // if the given number matches the current number
            continue; // then skip
        newcontactList[i++] = e;
    }
    num_entries--; // decrease the number of entries by 1;
    contactList = newcontactList;
}
private static void removeEntry2(String lname) {
    Entry[] newcontactList = new Entry[contactList.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(Entry e : contactList) {
        if(e == null) break; // if an entry is null then break the loop
        if(e.lname.equals(lname)) // if the given number matches the current number
            continue; // then skip
        newcontactList[i++] = e;
    }
    num_entries--; // decrease the number of entries by 1;
    contactList = newcontactList;
}
private static void removeEntry1(String number) {
    Entry[] newcontactList = new Entry[contactList.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(Entry e : contactList) {
        if(e == null) break; // if an entry is null then break the loop
        if(e.number.equals(number)) // if the given number matches the current number
            continue; // then skip
        newcontactList[i++] = e;
    }
    num_entries--; // decrease the number of entries by 1;
    contactList = newcontactList;
}
private static void sortListByPhoneNumber() {
    int i;
    Entry temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < num_entries; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < num_entries; i++) {
            if (contactList[j].number.compareToIgnoreCase(contactList[i].number) > 0) {
                temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = contactList[i];
                contactList[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    listAllContacts();
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot a `break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `break;` here:

```
case 'f':
                code = stdin.next();
                stdin.nextLine();
                i = index(code);
case 'l':
                listAllContacts(); break;
```

Thus your find `f` runs into your list `l`.

Simply add a break before your case so the two don't run into each other.

Comment: Using break did fix the problem. Thanks. I'm still new to programming, and me and my peer mentors kept looking at the index method for the problem.